# Add multiple post meta keys from multiple select

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type that has several fields that all get saved to the database just fine, except for one.

I have a `<select>` field which allows selecting multiple values:

```
<select name="people[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php 
        
        $args = array( 
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'any',
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'order'         => 'ASC'
        );
        $all_posts = get_posts($args);   

        foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
            </option>
        <?php
        }

    ?>
</select>
```

...but the problem is I can't seem to create a meta key value for each of the items that were selected when the page is published.

This is what I am trying to achieve but it doesn't work:

```
$the_people =  get_post_meta($post_id, 'people', TRUE);

foreach ($the_people as $people) { 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'people', $people );
}
```

**Expected Behaviour**

When someone selects a couple of posts from the `select` field (let's pretend post ID 1 and post ID 2 were initially selected) and the page is published, then a **meta_key** called 'people' with no value needs to be created for both posts 1 and 2, like this:

[image]

Comment: so what is the result now? Nothing is saved ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe im fully missing the point but shouldn't that be:

```
$the_people =  isset($_POST["people"]) ? $_POST["people"] : array();

foreach ($the_people as $people) { 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'people', $people );
}
```

because to actually save the data you need to first read them from your $_POST var. If you start directly by reading it from the DB when no data has been saved yet i guess you will never find what you want

Comment: Thanks. That nearly works, but it gave me a clue. This works: `update_post_meta( $people, 'people', '' );`